# return user.uid onAuthStateChanged

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have small function and it works when I look in console: returns user.uid in console but I want to return uid to use in other function

```
newUserUid() {
return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
   console.log(user.uid);
  }
});
}
```

I want to function return uid like this: `ewfwe3423sdfsdakmasd`

Comment: you should store it there or set in class variable. [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) returns unsubscribe function

Comment: can you show mes sample please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` to the auth state. You are using the `JavaScript` SDK inside an `Angular 2` app, use the `AngularFire2` SDK instead.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
...
constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth) {}
...

someOtherFunction() {
    newUserUid().subscribe(auth => {
        // Now use value 
        if (auth) {
            console.log(auth.uid);
        } else {
           // logged out
        }
    });
}

newUserUid() {
    return this.af.auth;
}
```

Refs: [Here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md) and [here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-2-firebase-authentication-7593c565fa53)