# what is returned on firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

When I hover over `onAuthStateChanged` it shows this:

```
(method) firebase.auth.Auth.onAuthStateChanged(nextOrObserver: firebase.Observer<any, any> | ((a: firebase.User) => any), error?: (a: firebase.auth.Error) => any, completed?: firebase.Unsubscribe): firebase.Unsubscribe
```

It also seems to work if I do `user: firebase.User`

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    console.log("data from stateChanged: ", user);
  })
```

But when I try to access the properties of user, i.e. user.uid then I get error basically saying inaccessible. So what exactly is the return type here and how do I access that?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

Comment: It says it returns function()
And then there is example below, but I'm in Angular2, so its breaking Typescript.

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795636/return-user-uid-onauthstatechanged

Comment: It seems odd. Firebase is created by Google, Angular is created by Google, yet the docs don't have any Angular specific examples. !! :)

Comment: Richards that's kind of it. But I need to register onAuthStateChanged. How would I do that?

Comment: I tried your code and `user.uid`  works fine for me. may be you need to check `if(user){...}` before printing right away.

Answer (score 4):

`onAuthStateChanged` returns either a `firebase.User` or `null`. You need to null guard it and potentially cast as a `firebase.User` in Typescript before accessing it's attributes.

I'd recommend using the AngularFire2 and it's AngularFireAuth module, if you're using Angular; we've smoothed over some of these API concerns and have wrapped the callbacks in RxJS Observables.

Comment: Would be great if you could give an example of what you mean for some Typescript rookies like me :)

Comment: if (user) { /* do something with user */ } else { ... }